# how to over come the stop script error in the browser when rendering large chart data using dojo

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, dojo, dojox.charting

I'm developing an application which involves complex charts. When trying to render large amount of data in the chart the browser became unresponsive and show the alert stating the stop script error. I'm in need to render those data in charts. is there any way to over come this problem.

I have tried the solution given in this [link](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2010/03/04/how-to-prevent-stop-running-this-script-message-in-browsers/). But problem still exist.

I use dojo1.8 for charting

Comment: How are you rendering that data? Are you using some kind of loop? (for, while, ...) or are you using something else. A loop-structure is synchronous as far as I know. You can try to work with callbacks, but the solution provided is also using callbacks so it's strange it doesn't work (since it's asynchronous). Also, when do you call the `render()` function? Can you post your code?

Comment: I had a challenging chart to do, to represent millions of data points... the browser simply cannot handle that amount of data. I had to resort to sampling in order to reduce the number of data points displayed. My charts worked well with a few thousand data points, but no more than that. Then I implemented zoom-in functions in order to get a more detailed view of a particular region of my chart. So basically, I think the answer is that, as of today, you probably cannot represent the number of data points you are trying to plot.